# shouldn't time to convert a stream to string be directly proportional to size?

Tags: java, android, json, networking, stream

I'm converting my network call input stream to a string before sending it to a JSON parser. here's the method I'm using right now (I'm trying out 6 other ways, for benchmarking purposes)

```
t3 =  System.currentTimeMillis();

    InputStream in = r.getEntity().getContent();
             /* BufferedReader and StringBuilder --> */

                StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String read = br.readLine(); // Delay Here! not in loop

                while(read != null) {
                    sb.append(read);
                    sb.append("\n");//No I18N
                    read =br.readLine();
                }
                 response =  sb.toString();
/*  */

long t4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            fileSize=response.length();
            System.out.println("APJSON:");
            System.out.println("\tD/A APJSON NWCallTime: \t\t"+Long.toString(t2-t1));
            System.out.println("\tD/A APJSON StringifyTime: \t\t"+Long.toString(t4-t3));
            System.out.println("\tD/A APTotalTime: \t\t"+Long.toString(t4-t1)+" "+Long.toString(t4-t0));
            System.out.println("\tD/A FileSize = \t\t"+Long.toString(fileSize));
            System.out.println("\tD/A Effective Speed = "+Long.toString(((long)fileSize)/(t2-t1))+ " kbps");
```

I've checked out some posts here on StackOverflow regarding this but my problem is not there. Here are some sample log data: (I'd post more, but these two are essentially representative of what im getting most of the time)

> I/System.out:     D/A APJSON NWCallTime:      2542
>   I/System.out:     D/A APJSON StringifyTime:       619
>   I/System.out:     D/A APTotalTime:        3161 3161
>   I/System.out:     D/A FileSize =      48969
>   I/System.out:     D/A Effective Speed = 19 kbps
>
> I/System.out:     D/A APJSON NWCallTime:      1027
>   I/System.out:     D/A APJSON StringifyTime:       1
>   I/System.out:     D/A APTotalTime:        1028 1029 .
>   I/System.out:     D/A FileSize =      2862
>   I/System.out:     D/A Network Speed = 2 kbps .

My question is, why the exponential increase when string size is larger? should'nt it be linear? does buffer size play a role in this?

Comment: No, it should be directly proportional to the peer response rate, as modified by any local memory allocation/garbage collection times. Your 'stringify time' includes all the network I/O as well. If the delay is in the first `readLine()`, presumably the peer is taking exponential time to build the response.

Comment: can you elaborate? i dont know what peer response rate is(tried googling it). is there any way i can reduce this time? i feel like 600ms is too much for 50kb of data

Comment: Peer response rate is the rate at which the peer responds. It's not magical terminology. Your measurements are not accurately decribed by the printouts.

Comment: this stream is obtained after the network call is finished right? so why should "peer response" matter?

Comment: You don't *know* that. You are *assuming* it.  There is no reason for this API to read the entire response from the network into memory before returning. It would just be a waste of space. It's far more likely that reads from that input stream read more or less directly from the network.

Comment: I checked the network monitor and the network activity takes place within the time show in my logs, as far as I can see

Comment: The fact that there is a delay in the first `readLine()` proves the point completely, and contradicts your last comment. In any case that delay is certainly not 'stringify time ''. It is entirely possible that *nothing* happens on the network, either send or receive, until the first read. This is how `HttpURLConnection` works, for example.

Comment: i see... so is the first time elapsed (i.e.) t2-t1 (code not shown here) just like a handshake only? and if i set my buffer size to a number greater than the maximum size of reply im expecting, can I read it completely in one go?

Comment: I can't possibly know what `t2-t1` is, as you haven't shown the code. How much you can read in one go depends on how fast it arrives, which depends on ... peer response rate. You will usually not get more than about 1500 bytes at a time if you read at the maximum rate, because of the path MTU.